# Working with threads

Tags: c#, multithreading

I am using 3d party library. 
And i have the following code:

```
 Session s = new Session(AuthParam.Login, AuthParam.Password);
 s.Connect();

 s.Connected += (sender, eventArgs) => 
        {
            _contactCollection = s.ContactList.Contacts.Select(x => new Contact(x.Nickname, x.Uin)).ToList();
        };

        s.ConnectionError += (sender, eventArgs) =>
        {

        };

 s.Dispose();
```

s.Connect working in separate thread. So i want stop executing function. Wait while raised events and then continie executing. How can i do it?

Comment: This is unclear. So `Connect()` is asynchronous? I really doubt. If that is so, then dispose will immediately kick in.

Answer (score 1):

Why could you not reorder your code such that the event handlers are added before calling `Connect`?

```
Session s = new Session(AuthParam.Login, AuthParam.Password);

s.Connected += (sender, eventArgs) => 
  {
    _contactCollection = s.ContactList.Contacts.Select(x => new Contact(x.Nickname, x.Uin)).ToList();
  };

s.ConnectionError += (sender, eventArgs) =>
  {
  };

s.Connect();
```

This way you are guarenteed to get the raised events caused by the `Connect` method since they are wired in *before* `Connect` is called.

There is really no way to prevent `Connect` from executing once it is called.<sup>1</sup>

<sup>1</sup><sub>I suppose you could execute `Connect` on a separate thread and then suspend that thread, but that is fraught with problems; too many to enumerate here.</sub>